# Python: error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, file-descriptor

I have error at:

```
"File "/home/pi/blescan.py", line 78, in hci_le_set_scan_parameters
    old_filter = sock.getsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, 14)

error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')"
```

I am unsure what is the cause of the error, and I have tried whatever solution that is available online, but it resulted in the same error.

```
DEBUG = False

import os
import sys
import struct
import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez
from time import gmtime, strftime


LE_META_EVENT = 0x3e
LE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS=0x00
LE_RANDOM_ADDRESS=0x01
LE_SET_SCAN_PARAMETERS_CP_SIZE=7
OGF_LE_CTL=0x08
OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_PARAMETERS=0x000B
OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_ENABLE=0x000C
OCF_LE_CREATE_CONN=0x000D

LE_ROLE_MASTER = 0x00
LE_ROLE_SLAVE = 0x01

# these are actually subevents of LE_META_EVENT
EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE=0x01
EVT_LE_ADVERTISING_REPORT=0x02
EVT_LE_CONN_UPDATE_COMPLETE=0x03
EVT_LE_READ_REMOTE_USED_FEATURES_COMPLETE=0x04

# Advertisment event types
ADV_IND=0x00
ADV_DIRECT_IND=0x01
ADV_SCAN_IND=0x02
ADV_NONCONN_IND=0x03
ADV_SCAN_RSP=0x04


def returnnumberpacket(pkt):
    myInteger = 0
    multiple = 256
    for c in pkt:
        myInteger +=  struct.unpack("B",c)[0] * multiple
        multiple = 1
    return myInteger 

def returnstringpacket(pkt):
    myString = "";
    for c in pkt:
        myString +=  "%02x" %struct.unpack("B",c)[0]
    return myString 

def printpacket(pkt):
    for c in pkt:
        sys.stdout.write("%02x " % struct.unpack("B",c)[0])

def get_packed_bdaddr(bdaddr_string):
    packable_addr = []
    addr = bdaddr_string.split(':')
    addr.reverse()
    for b in addr: 
        packable_addr.append(int(b, 16))
    return struct.pack("<BBBBBB", *packable_addr)

def packed_bdaddr_to_string(bdaddr_packed):
    return ':'.join('%02x'%i for i in struct.unpack("<BBBBBB",bdaddr_packed[::-1]))

def hci_enable_le_scan(sock):
    hci_toggle_le_scan(sock, 0x01)

def hci_disable_le_scan(sock):
    hci_toggle_le_scan(sock, 0x00)

def hci_toggle_le_scan(sock, enable):
    cmd_pkt = struct.pack("<BB", enable, 0x00)
    bluez.hci_send_cmd(sock, OGF_LE_CTL, OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_ENABLE, cmd_pkt)


def hci_le_set_scan_parameters(sock):
    old_filter = sock.getsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, 14)



    SCAN_RANDOM = 0x01
    OWN_TYPE = SCAN_RANDOM
    SCAN_TYPE = 0x01


def parse_events(sock, loop_count=100):
    old_filter = sock.getsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, 14)

    CurrentTime = strftime("%H:%M,%S", gmtime())
    flt = bluez.hci_filter_new()
    bluez.hci_filter_all_events(flt)
    bluez.hci_filter_set_ptype(flt, bluez.HCI_EVENT_PKT)
    sock.setsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, flt )
    done = False
    results = []
    myFullList = []
    for i in range(0, loop_count):
        pkt = sock.recv(255)
        ptype, event, plen = struct.unpack("BBB", pkt[:3])
        #print "--------------" 
        if event == bluez.EVT_INQUIRY_RESULT_WITH_RSSI:
                i =0
        elif event == bluez.EVT_NUM_COMP_PKTS:
                i =0 
        elif event == bluez.EVT_DISCONN_COMPLETE:
                i =0 
        elif event == LE_META_EVENT:
            subevent, = struct.unpack("B", pkt[3])
            pkt = pkt[4:]
            if subevent == EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE:
                le_handle_connection_complete(pkt)
            elif subevent == EVT_LE_ADVERTISING_REPORT:
                #print "advertising report"
                num_reports = struct.unpack("B", pkt[0])[0]
                report_pkt_offset = 0
                for i in range(0, num_reports):

                    if (DEBUS == True):
                        print "-------------"
                        print "\tMAC address: ",        packed_bdaddr_to_string(pkt[report_pkt_offset + 3:report_pkt_offset + 9])
                        TxPower, = struct.unpack("b",  pkt[report_pkt_offset -2])
                        print "\tTxpower:", -TxPower
                        rssi, = struct.unpack("b", pkt[report_pkt_offset -1])
                        print "\tRSSI:", rssi
                        print "\tTime:", CurrentTime
                    # build the return string
                    Adstring = packed_bdaddr_to_string(pkt[report_pkt_offset + 3:report_pkt_offset + 9])
                    Adstring += ","
                    Adstring += returnstringpacket(pkt[report_pkt_offset -22: report_pkt_offset - 6])
                    Adstring += ","
                    Adstring += "%i" % returnnumberpacket(pkt[report_pkt_offset -6: report_pkt_offset - 4])
                    Adstring += ","
                    Adstring += "%i" % returnnumberpacket(pkt[report_pkt_offset -4: report_pkt_offset - 2])
                    Adstring += ","
                    Adstring += "%i" % struct.unpack("b", pkt[report_pkt_offset -2])
                    Adstring += ","
                    Adstring += "%i" % struct.unpack("b", pkt[report_pkt_offset -1])
                    #print "\tAdstring=", Adstring
                    myFullList.append(Adstring)
                done = True
    sock.setsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, old_filter )
    return myFullList
```

Full Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/blescan.py", line 79, in hci_le_set_scan_parameters
    old_filter = socket.getsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, 14)
error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/testblescan.py", line 15, in <module>
    blescan.hci_enable_le_scan(socket)
  File "/home/pi/blescan.py", line 67, in hci_enable_le_scan
    hci_toggle_le_scan(socket, 0x01)
  File "/home/pi/blescan.py", line 74, in hci_toggle_le_scan
    bluez.hci_send_cmd(socket, OGF_LE_CTL, OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_ENABLE, cmd_pkt)
error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: @KlausD. Im new to python, with very little knowledge and experience. I really appreciate if you could explain the error to me. Thank you.

Comment: The error indicates, that the socket is in a state in which it can not accept your commands. This usually happens when you try to re-use an already closed socket, or it has been closed otherwise.

Comment: So what does this mean? Is there a way to maybe open back the socket? Or a way to solve this issue?

Comment: No, trying that will actually result in this error. You have not posted the code that creates and hold the socket over it's lifetime. Maybe something is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for helping ! Have managed to solve the issue, there was something wrong with the bluetooth dongle which caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The output appears to be reporting an OSError, which is accompanied by an error code. This isn't a Python-specific problem, because it is being raised by the underlying operating system.

You can use the [standard library's `errno` feature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html) to get information about the operating system's error codes.

You can also ask for the description of an error code via [the `os.strerror` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.strerror):

```python
import os

os.strerror(9)   # Returns the text value “Bad file descriptor”.
```

So, something your program is doing makes use of a file descriptor (the integer that represents an input/output stream in the running program) that doesn't actually have a file attached. The operating system complains, and Python reports that as an OSError.

You can interrogate [the OSError object you catch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) for its error code (the `errno` attribute) and what filename was reported (the `filename` attribute):

```python
try:
    do_the_thing()
except OSError as exc:
    logger_for_this_program(
            "Got OSError (code {exc.errno:d}, filename {exc.filename})".format(
                exc=exc))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping ! Have managed to solve the issue, there was something wrong with the bluetooth dongle which caused the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer addresses your question, please vote it up; if you think it is correct, please accept it as the answer.